# Движение против часовой стрелки Python

Tags: python, массивы, list

Пишу мини-игру но застрял на этапе движения числа против часовой стрелки. У меня есть 2 списка

```
rival = [0,3,3,3]
   my = [3,0,6,0]
```

И при вызове game(my, rival, 2), я хочу получить такой результат

```
rival = [1,4,4,4]
   my = [4,0,0,1]
```

То есть мы берём 6 обнуляем её, и приплюсовываем против часовой стрелки. Буду очень благодарный за помощь, я уже запутался :)
Вот мой код:

```
def game(my, rival, pos):
    for i in range(len(my)):
        if i <= x:
            my[i] += 1
            my[pos] = 0
```

Comment: Вы сами прочитали, что написали? "берём 6" -   почему именно "6", но предположим.  "обнуляем её" -  понятно, если есть ответ на предыдущий вопрос.   "приплюсовываем против часовой стрелки"  что приплюсовываем? Почему к соседнему нулю ничего не "приплюсовано" а остальные элементы изменились. Если все элементы изменились, то почему "против часовой стрелки".  Какое ко всему этому имеет отношение первый список если в коде он даже не упоминается? Не удивительно, что при такой сумбурности мыслей "вы уже запутались". Попробуйте свою мысль выразить четче, что бы ее можно было понять.

Comment: @passant Мне нужно с этих двух списков rival = [0,3,3,3] и my = [3,0,6,0] получить такой результат rival = [1,4,4,4] my = [4,0,0,1]. Например, я хочу взять 6 с нижнего списка разделить его на единицы и добавлять к каждому следующему элементу единицу, против часовой стрелки.

Comment: Всё в принципе понятно, непонятно по какому принципу берётся элемент 6?

Comment: @CrazyElf, Если вызвать функцию game(my, rival, 2), то он берёт индекс от списка "my". То есть в списке my индекс 2 = 6. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете решить это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
def game(my, rival, x):
    y = 1
    lst = [rival, my]
    val, lst[y][x] = lst[y][x], 0
    d = 1
    while val > 0:
        x += d
        if x < 0:
            d = -d
            y = 1 - y
            x = 0
        if x >= len(my):
            d = -d
            y = 1 - y
            x = len(my) - 1
        lst[y][x] += 1
        val -= 1

rival = [0,3,3,3]
my = [3,0,6,0]
game(my, rival, 2)
print(rival)
print(my)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 4, 4, 4]
[4, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Могу как-то с Вами связать помимо stackoverflow?

Comment: @BrzzzZz t.me/Crazy_Elf

Answer (score 0):

Странная задача, но тем не менее:

Сама функция:

```
def game(my, rival, pos):
    sp=rival+my[::-1]
    for i in range(len(rival)-2+pos,len(rival)-2+pos-my[pos],-1):
        sp[i]+=1
    rival=sp[0:len(rival)]
    my=sp[len(rival):][::-1]
    my[pos]=0
    return(rival,my)
```

Вызов:

```
rival = [0,3,3,3]
my=[3,0,6,0]
pos=2
rival,my=game(my,rival,pos)
print(rival)
print(my)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 4, 4, 4]
[4, 0, 0, 1]
```

Оно?